# Functional analysis self-study book

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, book-recommendation

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for here, so fair enough if it gets closed/down-voted.

I'm self-studying mathematics, did basic real analysis (Riemann, not Lebesgue integraton) and complex analysis, and I'd like to move on to functional analysis shortly.

I have two books: Muscat's Functional Analysis (Universitext), and Axler's Measure, Integration and Real Analysis (GTM).

It seems to me that Muscat is rigorous but still lighter (not meant in a bad way) on the maths, but covers more topics than Axler. But Axler spends a lot of time on measure theory (of course) and does also  cover the basics of Hilbert spaces and Banach spaces and linear operators on Hilbert spaces.

At this moment I'm more inclined to start with Axler, since I suspect after covering Axler I'll have a stronger foundation and more easily pick up on the topics covered in Muscat but not in Axler. Would this be wise? Other recommended books welcome.